# How to Access XHR Object making backbone.model save

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, backbone.js

By using ajax I can access the XHR Object simply making:

```
$.ajax().fail(function (XHR) {
     // some code
});
```

When saving a backbone model:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    saveModel: function () {
        this.myModel.save({
            error: this.onError
        });
    }


    onError: function (xhr) {
       // how to access xhr?
    }

});
```

How should I get XHR when I save a `backbone.model` onError server event?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call any of the functions that go through Backbone.Sync, Backbone returns a reference to the XHR:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/some/path/that/is/an/error/"
});

var myModel = new MyModel();

xhr = myModel.save( {} , {
    error: function(model, response) {
        console.log(xhr);            
    }
});
```

Also, note that [`Model.save()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) takes 2 arguments - properties to change before saving, and the options hash as a second argument.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/8AVjy/7/

**Post Comment:**

I've never really needed to do it, but this is what I'd probably do:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/some/path/that/is/an/error/"
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    saveModel: function () {
        that = this;
        xhr = this.model.save({}, {
            error: function (model, resp) {
                that.onError(xhr);
            }
        });
    },

    onError: function (xhr) {
       // how to access xhr?
        console.log(xhr);            
    }

});

var myModel = new MyModel();

var myView = new MyView({model: myModel});

myView.saveModel();
```

An updated jsFiddle for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/8AVjy/14/